# Scipy cdist maximum distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

New to scipy. I am trying to use the cdist function to pick the greatest distance between vectors. My attempt is

```
dm = cdist(XA, XB, lambda u, v: np.max(np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum())))
```

but it doesn't seem to produce the correct result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cdist` function returns a NxM matrix containing all distances between the N vectors of XA and M vectors of XB. If you want the max distance, regardless of the vectors that originate it, you need to `ravel()` the 2D array into a 1D array and then look for the `max()` value:

```
dm = cdist(XA, XB,metric='euclidean').ravel().max()
```

Comment: You don't need to ravel first, `cdist(XA, XB).max()` would work fine.

Comment: Well done @kwinkunks, sometimes I forget how smart Python is